# Constructing Twilio Flow with opt in text message at the end of call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-studio

We are trying to have a phone flow where the customer calls in and in the end they receive a text message asking for their name, which they respond to, and then receive a response asking another follow-up question. An example below:

- *call*
- Us: (SMS) Thanks for participating! What is your name for our website?
- Them: (SMS) John Smith
- Us: (SMS) Thanks John Smith!Would you like to be    notified when it is
  online?
- Them: (SMS) Yes
- Us: (SMS)Take care!

We have structured this by having a Send & Wait widget which sends the initial message for the name and another one for the notification message.

We disabled the concurrent callers feature such that the user is kept in the same session, but this creates other issues. In order to try and solve these issues, we have written code that terminates executions for completed calls. But this code appears to be too large to run for the Twilio call handle POST link.

We were wondering what advice you might have for constructing a flow like the one described above and how we could best accomplish that considering what different options we've done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So during the voice phone call portion, are you receiving verbal opt-in to send the party follow-up SMS Messages?

One option is to use the Studio HTTP Request Widget or Run Function Widget to start another Studio flow focused on the SMS portion via the REST API Trigger. You can send the relevant information into this new execution using the parameters key, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API.

You should do a [lookup](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/api) on the number they call in from, to make sure it is a mobile device capable of supporting SMS to offer this option.

Not sure I understand the issue you encountered, ...this code appears to be too large to run for the Twilio call handle POST link...

Also for Studio Voice flows, always set the statusCallback URL and the Primary Handler Fails URL to the Studio Webhook URL found under the trigger widget of your flow, as called out here, to mitigate stuck executions.

[Configuring Your Twilio Number for Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#configuring-your-twilio-number-for-studio)

Comment: Hi! No -- we have them press 1 to opt in at the end and it hangs up and then they receive the text -- should have made that more clear -- my apologies!


We are currently getting Error - 11750: TwilML response body too large



That lookup is a good idea! I will look into the Run Function to start a new flow -- my confusion with that is to how to not treat the incoming text as a new trigger in that new flow, but this execution method is a good idea to look for it. 


Thanks! :)